# Update possibly ruined my setup

Tags: networking, server, updates, ssh

I was running what I believe was ubuntu 18.04...(SEE COMMENTS AT BOTTOM) I dont honestly remember the version at this point. Today I updated to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Prior to the update everything was working fine. The machine is used to host PLEX, Home Assistant, Portainer, and some other random containers that are used within Home Assistant for my ZWave devices and security cameras. My version of Ubuntu is headless so I always SSH into it and access homeassistant through local IP addresses. After the update I was unable to SSH into at all. I figured "no big deal the IP address got changed I just have to check what IP address its using and Ill be good"
Well that wasnt the case. The computer is still displaying the same IP address as before only when I check the device list in my router that LAN port is labeled as "Allocation: Pending"... I assumed this was my only issue and that I needed to somehow reset my allocation on my computers side as its trying to force that IP address. I have tried nearly everything and nothing seems to work. I cannot access any of my containers through local IP addresses. I can not SSH into the server and for the life of me I can not figure out exactly what is causing this issue or how to fix it.

Like I said I tried everything I could to fix this issue by googling what I assumed was causing it and nothing has been able to fix it. I am not sure if updating caused some issue with Docker, or networking, or what at this point. I just want to be able to access my containers and get my plex server and home assistant back up. I forgot how much I hated getting up to turn off the lights.

I can provide whatever additional info is needed. I am honestly at a complete loss at this point. Thanks in advance to whatever Linux wizard can fix this.

EDIT in response to comments:
I have been using keyboard and mouse to directly interact with the server.

I have restarted my router and the IP address shown for my computer differ from what is shown in Linux.

I now understand there is no upgrade path from the original version of linux to that in which I am running after update. When I SSHed into my server yesterday I was prompted with "a newer version is available run "COMMAND" to upgrade" Or something along those lines. I simply typed in whatever the command was. I believe it was something along the lines of do-release-update maybe.

Im very new to linux and most of my issues have been fairly simple to figure out so I am trying to explain things the best I can

Comment: Just to clarify for everyone else. I have been using a keyboard/mouse/monitor to try and diagnose this. The inability to SSH after update is simply what caused me to realize there was an issue. Simply provided it as I dont know if being unable to SSH is an indicator of any specific issue if someone sees this and recognizes the fault. Was just trying to provide as much info as I could. Also as I stated I cannot remember the exact version as I didnt check it before updating. I have checked netplan and it appears to be fine from what I can tell.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1426684/edit) to provide clarifications and provide additional information. Comments are intended only to help you improve your question until it is answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Comment: You've tagged your question as being about Ubuntu 12.04 or the 2012-April release??? The mention of a *unsupported* upgrade path implies you didn't use [ubuntu-release-upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) tools and did something different, so please clarify or correct details.  How did you upgrade?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS had two upgrade paths; (1) to the next release (ie. Ubuntu 18.10) but that closed when 18.10 went EOL back in 2019, and (2) to the next LTS release which is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, an *supported* release thus that option is still offered.  Your question says 18.04 which has no offered upgrade to 22.04; only Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does (*and it opened only in recent weeks after [22.04.1 was released](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/08/12/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-released/)*) so it's very likely you were on 20.04 (& not 18.04) - but the 18.04 -> 22.04 implies major problems, likely corruption.

Comment: If your system was a *corrupted* 18.04 (*bionic*) one, which included some *focal* sources; the upgrade shouldn't have been expected to work unless you removed the corruption first; as you'll have upgraded potentially to the wrong release (ie. *jammy* or 22.04 instead of *focal* or 20.04). Restoring backups is the best way, or install a later version then restore backups of your data.  The 18.04 -> 22.04 highlights a problem with your system prior to upgrade (*if you were on 18.04*) that should have been corrected prior to *release-upgrade*.

Comment: I'd likely look for clues as to what you were on; and check what is in your sources now & what was there.  Some clues are always there (ie. *release-upgrade* procedures usually disable sources and not remove them, so look for disabled - and if you're like me your own notes/comments will show sources you manually disabled anyway). Further you can explore `/var/log/dist-upgrade/` but your question highlights uncorrected issues prior to upgrade as the problem & you've not provided clues on that.

Comment: can you ping the IP? can you access internet from that machine? can you try `nc -l -p 1234` on "server" , and, `nc ipaddresshere 1234` or `nmap -sT ipaddresshere -p 1234`from client to see if it's a problem with SSH, network, or firewall?